# Windows Store apps on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows-server-2012

I've tried installing my Metro App on a Windows Server 2012 Standard, but apparently I can't run any Metro app using the built-in administrator accout. As it's not my server, I would prefere not to create any other user accounts. I've read something on the internet about the UAC enable/disabled. In this momment the UAC is enabled. So is there something that I can change to make it work ? Having the move from one account to another all the time would be very annoying because of the purpose of the server itself : always logging out and than back in.

*I mention that I installed my Metro app using sideloading, if this matter in any way, but I don't think so, as all the Metro apps are blocked.

Answer (score 1):

You need a microsoft account to install apps from the store. If UAC is really disabled then your local administrator account is probably not connected to a microsoft account.

Comment: It is enabled, as I sad in the initial post. Also, the admin account is connected with the microsoft account. I also have a developer license for that PC.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the Built-In Administrator to run Metro Apps, do this:

1. Launch the Local Group Policy Editor (GPEDIT.msc)
2. Browse to Computer Configuration, Windows Settings, Security Settings,Local Policies and then Security Options.
3. Enable the following setting "User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the Built-in Administrator Account"
4. Restart your computer